# How to design/model a has many relationship that has a meaningful join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wasn't able to put well into words (in Question title) what I'm trying to do, so in honor of the saying that an image is worth a thousand words; In a nutshell what I'm trying to do is..

[image]

Basically, what I have is **A Teacher has many Appointments** and **A Student has many Appointments** which roughly translates to:

[image]

I'm trying to stay away from using the **has_and_belongs_to_many** macro, because my **appointments** model has some meaning(operations), for instance it has a Boolean field: *confirmed*.

So, I was thinking about using the **has_many :through** macro, and perhaps using an "Appointable" join table model? What do you guys think?

The Scenario I'm trying to code is simple;

1. A Student requests an Appointment with a Teacher at certain Date/Time
2. If Teacher is available (and wants to give lesson at that Date/Time), She confirms the Appointment.

I hope you can tell me how would you approach this problem? Is my assumption of using the has_many :through macro *correct*?

Thank you!

Comment: +1 for the diagrams! Your problem is similar to [the one in the rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) about `has_many :through` associations.

Comment: You want a single Appointment to have multiple students and multiple teachers?

Comment: `has_many :though` is the correct approach for this.

Comment: @ – Deefour No, a single Appointment record belongs to a Teacher AND belongs to a Student, also... it will have some operations to it, like being confirmed. I was wondering what the join model should be like when using the has_many :through macro?

Comment: @sergelerator OH YES! I hadn't realized that before! Kudos for that one, sir! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both teachers and students could inherit from a single class e.g. Person. Then create an association between Person and Appointments. This way you keep the architecture open so that if in the future you want to add 'Parents' then they could easily be integrated and may participate in appointments.

It may not be completely straightforward how you do the joins with the children classes (Students, Parents, Teachers). It may involve polymorphic relationships which I don't particularly like. You should though get away with a single join table.

In any case, you want to design so that your system can be extended. Some extra work early on will save you a lot of work later.

Comment: Actually, it's a good comment, and the good news is, that I already have the implementation that you mentioned in place :) My parent class is User (and its children are: Student and Teacher of course)